# How can make firefox do this work?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'm using Vimperator with firefox, and I find i always type the same URL, for example I type " http://gigapedia.info/1/@title C++ " to search a ebook with "C++" include in title, How can i just type "C++" and can get the complete URL?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What does this have to do with Vimperator? Also, when I go to http://gigapedia.info/1/@title%20c++, it gives me 'nothing found'.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also not sure what you want. However this may be helpful:

- Create a bookmark.
- The location should be something like `http://gigapedia.info/google?cx=partner-pub-0811008802470909:3vu8gy-n059&cof=FORID:10&ie=UTF-8&q=c%s&sa=Search&siteurl=gigapedia.info/`  The %s will be replaced by what you type after the keyword.
- Set the keyword to something like `g`

You can now search via FireFox's location bar by typing: `g c++`

It'll then take you to: http://gigapedia.info/google?cx=partner-pub-0811008802470909:3vu8gy-n059&cof=FORID:10&ie=UTF-8&q=c%2B%2B&sa=Search&siteurl=gigapedia.info/

You can do this for any URL that takes a param.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Quix bookmarklet](http://quixapp.com/), a command line-like interface for your browser, for which you can write your own commands.